# Using Push State in a Marionette Application for SEO

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, marionette

I did my homework and read through this mini series about pushstate:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-2-progressive-enhancement-with-backbone-js/

From what understand the hard part of implementing push state is making sure that my server side is going to serve the actual pages for the corresponding urls.

I feel like this is going to be a HUGE task, previously I was just sending a simple jade page as simple as:

```
 body

    header

    section
        div#main

    footer.site-footer
        div.footer-icons.footer-element
        div.footer-element
          span.footer-link Contact Us
          span.footer-link Terms of Service

script(src='/javascripts/lib/require.js', data-main='/javascripts/application.js')
```

and I was doing all the rendering with my Marionette Layouts and Composite Views, and to be honest it was a bit complicated.

So from what I understand I need to replicate all that complicated nesting/rendering using jade on the server side for pushState to work properly?

I used underscore templates in the client-side, what is an easy way to re-use them on the server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I depends on what you want to do...

To "just" use pushState, the only requirement is that your server returns a valid page for each URL that can be reached by your app. However, the content returned by the server does *NOT* have to match what will get rendered client side. In other words, you could use a "catch all" route on the server side that always returns the page you have above, and then let Backbone/Marionette trigger its route to handle the rendering and display.

That said, if you want to use pushState for SEO, you likely want to have the static HTML sent by the server on the first call, then have the Marionette app start to enhance the interactivity. In this case, it is much more complex and you might want to experiment with using options to trigger the proper behavior (e.g. using attachView when enhancing existing HTML, showing views normally after that initial case).

Comment: Yes the only reason I want to use pushState is SEO, but i am intimidated by the extra work i am going to do. I was thinking of a hybrid (some of my pages are server side rendered and some of them client side) approach is that considered bad practice. But even with a hybrid approach my client side code gets confusing, because I have multiple entry points. So would that mean I need to have several Marriontte object instances for each entry point?

Comment: I don't think a hybrid approach would be considered a bad practice. And I don't think you should need multiple objects. You simply need to be able to properly start your application (i.e. in the right state) depending on the options received. Then, adapt the options given to the application according to the entry point.

Answer (score 1):

Push state can work properly WITHOUT your server actually serving your application in the way that is suggested.

Push state is merely an alternative to `hashbang` url's, and it is supported in modern browsers. Check out [the history docs here](http://backbonejs.org/#History), you will see there is no mention of having your site serve your application statically at the url's for your application (but bear in mind it is opt-in).

What the article you reference is saying, is that **for good SEO**, you should do this. That's because you cannot guarantee when a search engine crawls your site, that it will execute your javascript, and pick up your routes etc. So serving the site statically is simply to give the search engine a way to get your content without executing any javascript.

Like you say, by doing this you are essentially building two sites in parallel, and it does literally double the amount of work you need to do. This may be ok if you're building a relatively simple site filled with static content, but if you are creating a complicated application, then it is probably too much in most situations.

Although I would add, if you are building an application, then SEO doesn't really matter, so it's a null point.